# Count String without Url

Tags: php, youtube

please am actually working a kind of social blog which supports the usually thing a blog should have like image upload, bbcodes with youtube videos and many more.

At the home page it shows all recent blog with a limit of 1000 characters.
the problem is that when i add youtube videos or images via links and it falls at the end of the the string it breaks the entire page.

please is there a way i can solve this? maybe some thing like counting the string with out the youtube videos and image link.

below is my homepage display code

```
              $csql =  $db->query("SELECT * FROM `icon_blog` WHERE `bstatus`='0'");
            if($csql->num_rows == 0){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-error">No Blog Available</div>';
            }else{
              $bpp = 3;
$pages = ceil($csql->num_rows/$bpp);
$page = intval($db->real_escape_string(isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : ''));
$begin = ($page >= 0 ? ($page*$bpp) : 0);

 $sql = $db->query("SELECT a.*, b.username FROM icon_blog a LEFT JOIN icon_admin b ON b.aid = a.uid WHERE a.bstatus='0' ORDER BY a.posttime DESC LIMIT ".$begin.", ".$bpp);
    //if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
 while($val = $sql->fetch_object()){
    //echo' <div class="well" style="border:1px solid #e3e3e3;border-radius:4px;min-height:1px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px; margin-bottom:10px;">';
    //echo'<div class="col-lg-8" style="border:1px solid #e3e3e3;border-radius:4px;">';
 //$fcontent = BBCode($val->message);
    $fcontent = $bb->parse(wordcensor($val->message));
   // $fcontent = $val->message;
    $bcom = $db->query("SELECT * FROM icon_bcomment WHERE bid='$val->bid'")->num_rows;
?><div class="[ panel panel-default ] panel-google-plus">
               <!--  <div class="panel-google-plus-tags">
                    <ul>
                        <li>#Snippet</li>
                    </ul>
                </div> -->
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 style="word-wrap:break-word;"><a href="index.php?bid=<?=$val->bid?>"><?=ucfirst($val->subject)?></a></h3>
                <!-- <h3>Robert McIntosh</h3> -->
                <h5><span>by <i><?=$val->username?></i></span> &middot; <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Comments (<?=$bcom?>) </a> &middot; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Posted on <i><?=date('d M Y h:i', $val->posttime)?></i></h5>
                   <!--  <h5><span>Shared publicly</span> - <span>Jun 25, 2014</span> </h5> -->
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p><?=nl2br(ucfirst(truncate($fcontent, '500')))?></p>

                             <? $chek =$db->query("SELECT * FROM icon_attachment WHERE postid='".$val->bid."' ORDER BY ctime DESC LIMIT 2");
        if ($chek->num_rows > 0) {
            while($gath = $chek->fetch_object()){
            echo '<div style="display:inline-block;padding-top:10px;padding-right:4px;padding-left:4px;margin-bottom:7px;" class="img-responsive"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="'.$site['site_url'].'uploads/'.$gath->file.'"></div>';
            }
        }?>
                </div>
                <div class="bs-social">
      <ul class="bs-social-buttons">
        <li class="facebook-button">
          <div class="fb-like" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div> </li>
        <!-- <li class="follow-btn">
          djdd
        </li> -->
        <li class="tweet-btn">
         <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
        </li>
        <li class="googleplus-button">
            <div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300" data-href=""></div>

<!-- Helyezd el ezt a címkét az utolsó +1 gomb címke mögé. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
            </div>

<? 
    }
    echo'<div class="text-center">
    <ul class="pager">';
$prev = $page-1;
$next = $page+1;
if($csql->num_rows >= 0) {
    if($begin/$bpp == 0) {
        echo '<li class="previous disabled">&larr;Newer&rarr;</li>';
    }else{
        echo '<li class="previous"><a href="?p='.($begin/$bpp-1).'">&larr;Newer&rarr;</a></li>';
    }
    if($begin+$bpp >= $csql->num_rows) {
        echo '<li class="next disabled">&larr;Older&rarr;</li>';
    }else{
        echo '<li class="next"><a href="?p='.($begin/$bpp+1).'">&larr;Older&rarr;</a></li>';
    }
}
echo'</ul>
</div>';
    }
echo'</div>';
}
```

Comment: You should not have Business Logic and HTML mixed together

Comment: pls explain, i do nt understand.

Comment: You should be using an MVC approach so In a controller class you fetch the posts and then checks them and then generate a view

Comment: Also you did not say which bbparser you are using

Comment: am new to webdesign, nt familiar with mvc its a bbparser by wookieb https://github.com/wookieb/bbcode

Comment: The documentation is in another language but you need to get the images and video and text separately and then echo them out in different divs so they are separated.

Comment: how do i make a work around it?

Comment: You need to read the documentation of the bb parser, I cant because its another language

Comment: any oda simple parser i use which u can wrk around with?